# EF: Custom Data Validation in IsValid()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a custom IsValid method in my model class. Method looks like this:

`public override bool IsValid(object value)
{`

```
// How I can get field name here for some data manipulation.

// some code for validation.
```

}

How I can get field name which is calling this custom IsValid method from controller??? 
I would really appreciate if you help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking a guess that this is what you mean.
Let's say that you know that the object you are validating is of type MyValidatableClass, having a property that should have the value "correct", you can do something like this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
  var objectToValidate = value as MyValidatableClass;

  // some code for validation.
  if (objectToValidate.SomeProperty != "correct")
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your reply. No, this is not my problem. Let me explain you more in details. I have two model fields

public HttpPostedFileBase File1 { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase File2 { get; set; }

File1 only accepting {.gif, .png, .jpg} and File2 only accepting {.doc, .pdf}. I need to validate both fields in my custom validator so user can upload only allowed files. I have a custom validator method as you mention above which is validating File1. Now the problem is that I cannot validate File2 because I dont know which field is calling this method.

Comment: Please let know if I am missing something or any better way to validate both fields in same method. 
I really appreciate if you have me in this regard. Thanks again.

Comment: you have to make model which has property that replicates to file . for e.g. public class Photo
{
    public virtual int PhotoId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhotoDescription { get; set; }
    [ImageValidation(ErrorMessage="Please select a PNG/JPEG image smaller than 10 MB")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
} as oerkelens has explained you have to override and use obj.File and check for valid extensions..